# Does Grapple / Constrict apply other Attack Effects?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, grapple, poison

[Reefclaws](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/reefclaw/) have 2 Claws +2 (1d4 + Grab + Poison) as their melee attack. They also have Constrict (1d4) as a Special Attack

If a Reefclaw succesfully grapples an opponent, decides to maintain the grapple in its next round and takes the "inflict damage" option following the succesful maintain, damage should go like this:

Successful Grapple: 1d4 Constrict Damage

Inflict Damage: 1d4 (because thats the damage of its natural attack)

Will the poison effect be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The reefclaw's poison notes that it is applied upon injury with the claw; dealing damage with the claw injures and therefore applies the poison.

Poison (Ex)
Claw—injury; save Fort DC 13; frequency 1/round for 4 rounds; effect 1d2 Str; cure 1 save.

The save DC is Constitution-based.

Comment: I believe you should substantiate that Grab and/or Grapple deal damage *with* the attack. Otherwise, the injury specifically relates to Claw attacks (which is not Constrict nor Grapple)